# When using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework is app.config neccessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

Say I have an application separated into several layers:

1. MVC
2. AzureCache
3. Services
4. Models
5. EntityFrameworkRepository

When adding the Windows Azure and Entity Framework Nuget packages to the `AzureCache` and `EntityFrameworkRepository` layers an `app.config` file gets added to each of the respective layers etc.  I was surprised to see that when I excluded these app.config files the app still ran.  I suppose I'm asking what purpose does the `app.config` serve if the settings are required/duplicate in the MVC project? Are the `app.config` even used at runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are the app.config even used at runtime?

No, absolutely not. They are as useful as garbage.

The only thing that matters and is used at runtime is the `web.config` file in your Web Application project. By the way that's the only *config* file that ever reaches your IIS deployment server. All the other `app.config` files added to some class libraries in your solution in Visual Studio is something you could throw away and have no remorse at all.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  They're as good as gone... But what are they actually used for?  Just for the developer to copy the necessary settings over to the web.config?

Comment: Yeap exactly for that. Technically the designers of the NuGet cannot possibly know which is the host application. So they spit a configuration file in the project you are installing the NuGet into, but cannot possibly know that this project is just a class library used by some other host web application. So you're gonna have to apply the setting in the web.config file of our host Web Application which is the only thing that gets deployed to IIS and the only thing that matters at runtime.

Comment: Actually lots of developers are confused by that thinking that what they are seeing in a Visual Studio solution is something that gets finally deployed. What you should be thinking is the final product that gets deployed to IIS. Which is just a web application with a web.config file, a bin folder with a couple of precompiled assemblies and that's absolutely all you end up with. There are no Visual Studio solutions, no app.config files, no .csproj files. no .cs files. IIS has strictly no knowledge of them at runtime.

Comment: Excellent response.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: when it comes to azure you can have the connection string in the service configuration file and in the application pass the connectionstring while initializing the context. Items in service config can be modified without a new deployment.